# Finding B supposing A and B|A are normal

Tags: multivariate-normal-distribution

Supposing that $A \sim \mathcal{N} ({\mathbf 0}, K_1), B \mid A \sim \mathcal{N} (A, K_2)$, then what is $B$?

I'm guessing that $B$ is also normal and there is a formula but I can't quite find it. A proof of the formula as well would also help.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior + the given references

Comment: @Tim Thanks that'll do I guess I'll look up the proof some other day.

Comment: You can find proofs in the references [4] and [5]